# Combobox bullet goes up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My comboboxes square bullets go to top like the image bellow is showing, I want to make it aligned to the associated text: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that in CSS just the following might do the job

```
position:relative;
top:10px; /* adjust as needed */
```